# Selecting a camera and outputting video when connecting multiple cameras in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, selection, leap-motion

I am trying to show AR video by connecting the hand tracking camera device (Leap motion: window device manager list: 0) and webcam camera (window device manager list: 1) in Unity.

Leap motion connects using the manufacturer's SDK and package files, so there is no need for additional coding to connect the camera in Unity.

The problem occurs when I connect a webcam camera (window device manager list: 1) in Unity and show AR video.

When the following code is applied to an object, if both Leap motion and webcam camera are connected, leap motion is recognized and output as video, and video output of webcam camera becomes impossible.

If only the webcam is connected after unplugging the leap motion from the PC, the video output of the webcam camera is possible.

I want to output video by selecting webcam camera (window device manager list: 1) on the object with both Leap motion and webcam camera connected to the PC.

Since I am a beginner in Unity, I need to simply modify it in the code below.

Waiting for help.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
public class WebCam : MonoBehaviour {
 
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        WebCamTexture web = new WebCamTexture(1280,720,60);
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = web;
        web.Play();
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a constructor of [`WebCamTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-ctor.html) that takes the parameter

> **deviceName**:   The name of the video input device to be used.

You can list all available devices via [`WebCamTexture.devices`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-devices.html) and get the name like e.g.

```
var devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
var webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture(devices[1].name);
```

You might also be able then to filter out the device you need like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

var device = devices.Select(d => d.name).FirstOrDefault(n => !n.Contains("Leap"));
```

For finding out how the cameras are called and to be able to filter by name you could print them all like e.g.

```
Debug.Log(string.Join("\n", devices.Select(d => d.name)));
```

Theoretically you could even feed them into a dropdown and let the user decide which device to use before creating the `WebCamTexture` then you wouldn't have to guess the name hardcoded at all ;)

---

Also note:

> Call [Application.RequestUserAuthorization](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.RequestUserAuthorization.html) before creating a WebCamTexture.